# Adding Address Fields to the Registeration form in Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

When a customer or user registers, I want to capture the address details in one click and save that in ps_address table , ie when he clicks on the register button his address details must be also saved to the ps_address table , how to do this?[image]

I have managed to customize the registration form and able to plug the address details form to my registration form as shown in the attached image  :

Now what I am stuck with is : when am clicking on the Register button ,the address field details are not saved in the database and I am getting server error

What I tried to do is ,I created  a new function called  processPostAddress and I am calling  processPostAddress from processSubmitAccount()  in controller/front/Authcontroller.php page before the redirection to the account page.

```
 $this->processPostAddress(); //// custom function call 
 Tools::redirect('index.php?controller='.(($this->authRedirection !== false) ? urlencode($this->authRedirection) : 'my-account'));
```

Below is the custom function which i created in controller/front/Authcontroller.php page

```
      public function processPostAddress()
    {
        if($this->context->customer->id_customer!=''){
        $address                = new Address();
        $address->id_customer   = 40;        
        $address->firstname     = trim(Tools::getValue('firstname'));
        $address->lastname      = trim(Tools::getValue('lastname'));
        $address->address1      = trim(Tools::getValue('address1'));
        $address->address2      = trim(Tools::getValue('address2'));
        $address->postcode      = trim(Tools::getValue('postcode'));
        $address->city          = trim(Tools::getValue('city'));
        $address->country       = trim(Tools::getValue('country'));
        $address->state         = trim(Tools::getValue('state'));
        $address->phone         = trim(Tools::getValue('phone'));
        $address->phone_mobile  = trim(Tools::getValue('phone_mobile'));
        $address->add(); // This should add the address to the addresss table             }
    }
```

Please  help me  or tell me if I am doing anything wrong or how to achieve this

Comment: "I am getting server error" could you post this error?

Comment: 500 Server Error
Oops, something went wrong.

Try to refresh this page or feel free to contact us if the problem persists.

Comment: Well you should have an explicit error in your error log files. Or you should put your Prestashop in debug mod from the config files to see the real error.

Comment: if i change  defines.inc.php line 42  define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true); will this help me in debugging or there is a more option to debug 
Sorry to ask since  am a  PrestaShop Newbie

Comment: `_PS_MODE_DEV_` should be true. `PS_DEBUG_PROFILING` is a usefull tool too but for optimisation. [Here you can have some more informations on the official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/PrestaShop's+developer+tools)

Comment: But the easiest way to get the error is to look at your apache error log files.

Comment: Some fields are required and you are not doing any validation... This is a very poor method of saving that address, in fact it's doomed to fail :D

Comment: alias validation was causing the problem 

 $this->errors = array_merge($this->errors, $address->validateFieldsRequiredDatabase());
       // Don't continue this process if we have errors !
    
        if (!$this->errors && !$this->ajax) {
            return;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding `$address->alias`, since alias was required and was validated .
Also in order to save in the database I modified  `$address->add();` to `$address->save();`

```
public function processPostAddress()
{       
    ///Address::postProcess(); // Try this for posting address  and check if its working
    // Preparing Address 
        $address                = new Address();
        $this->errors           = $address->validateController();
        $address->id_customer   = (int)$this->context->customer->id;        
        $address->firstname     = trim(Tools::getValue('firstname'));
        $address->lastname      = trim(Tools::getValue('lastname'));
        $address->address1      = trim(Tools::getValue('address1'));
        $address->address2      = trim(Tools::getValue('address2'));
        $address->postcode      = trim(Tools::getValue('postcode'));
        $address->city          = (int)trim(Tools::getValue('city'));
        $address->country       = (int)trim(Tools::getValue('country'));
        $address->state         = (int)trim(Tools::getValue('state'));
        $address->phone         = trim(Tools::getValue('phone'));
        $address->alias         = "My Default Address";

    // Check the requires fields which are settings in the BO
    $this->errors = array_merge($this->errors, $address->validateFieldsRequiredDatabase());
         // Don't continue this process if we have errors !

    if (!$this->errors && !$this->ajax) {
        return;
    }else{
         // Save address
        $address->save();
    }           
}
```

Comment: Why `if (!$this->errors) return;`? That means if no error is found, address is not saved?